Issue with Upgrading @nuxt/image Module in Nuxt 3
I'm encountering an issue while upgrading from @nuxt/image-edge to the latest stable @nuxt/image in my Nuxt 3 project. My current setup includes:

Nuxt version: "^3.1.1"
Vue version: "^3.2.45"
@nuxt/image version: "latest"

After updating the module, I receive the following error during the build:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:/.../node_modules/@nuxt/image/dist/runtime/composables' in 'node_modules@nuxt\image\dist\runtime\components'
  Did you mean 'composables.mjs'?
  BREAKING CHANGE: The request 'C:/.../node_modules/@nuxt/image/dist/runtime/composables' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
  (probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '.mjs' file, or a '.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
  The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
  Add the extension to the request.

Also I changed Nuxt Image to my nuxt.config.ts:
modules: [
    '@nuxt/image',
],


Please provide a reproduction, for example via stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/github/nuxt/starter/tree/v3

Try resetting you project node modules:

Delete package-lock.json
Delete node_modules folder
Delete .nuxt folder

Then make sure you have the latest @nuxt/image listed in your dependencies and included in the nuxt.config.ts module array, and run the install command.

Thanks for your reply but i already did that and i have the same error.
Also i have this error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@vueuse/head' in 'composables' except of the above error.
